# How can add something to the clipboard such that it is an indented bulleted list in Powerpoint when pasted?

Tags: javascript, clipboard, rtf

I want to give users on my webpage the option of copying something to their clipboard. When this is pasted in a powerpoint slide, it will be two bulleted items, with the second one indented

I have the library 'html-to-rtf' which takes some html (nested ul/li items) and spits out some RTF formatted text, but I need to get that as whatever format in the clipboard so that it doesn't paste as that text, but as the RTF-formatted text

So if I have 'Item One' and 'Item Two' known, I want to create the following in powerpoint:

- Item One

  - Item Two

Answer (score 0):

Found a way of doing exactly what I wanted:

```
      function listener(e) {
        e.clipboardData.setData("text/html", html);
        e.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", html);
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      document.addEventListener("copy", listener);
      document.execCommand("copy");
      document.removeEventListener("copy", listener);
```

where html is a string of html text, like for my use would be

```
<ul>
<li>Item One
<ul>
<li>Item Two</li>
</ul></li>
</ul>
```